# Remove carriage return and space from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, space, carriage-return

I want to remove carriage return and space from a string
for exemple:

```
var t ="     \n \n    aaa \n bbb \n ccc \n";
```

I want to have as result:

```
t = "aaa bbb ccc"
```

I use this one, it removes carriage return but I still have spaces

```
t.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: add \s to it: `/[\s\n\r]/g`

Comment: @vp_arth what's the point to include `\n` and `\r` if `\s` already matches them?

Comment: Maybe I wrong... I remember some about lineends and global flag.. may be about a point? sorry)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try:

```
 t.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
```

Then:

```
 t.replace(/\s{2,10}/g, ' ');
```

The 2nd one should get rid of more than 1 space

Answer (score 24):

Or you can do using single regex:

```
t.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
```

Also you will need to call `.trim()` because of leading and trailing spaces. So the full one will be:

```
t = t.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
```

Comment: and I still call replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'') for this :) Need to review updates)

Comment: @tenub I replace multiple whitespaces with single space. So if there were leading whitespaces, there will be leading space. If there were trailing whitespaces, there will be trailing space. We get rid of them using `.trim()`. EDIT: oops, @tenub already deleted the question.

Comment: This worked for me whereas the [other popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22921273/836169) did not catch my case.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest

- to clear carriage return => space
- to replace multiple spaces by a single one
- to clear leading and trailing spaces (same as jQuery trim())

Thus

```
t.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, ' ').replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic! thanks for sharing Ulugbek. I used the following code to have comma separated values from a barcode scanner. Anytime the barcode scanner button is pressed, carriage returns and spaces are converted to commas.

Java Script:

```
function KeyDownFunction() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("<%=txtBarcodeList.ClientID %>");
    txt.value = txt.value.replace(/\s+/g, ',').trim();
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBarcodeList" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="100"
                    Rows="6" onKeyDown="KeyDownFunction()"></asp:TextBox>
```